# How to tell if authenticated

Tags: angular, authentication

I'm using the ng-oidc-client package and in the navbar i am trying to use a ngIf statement. The problem i am having is determining if the user is authenicated.

```
// -------------------- navbar.component.ts ---------------
// Imports for the library
import { OidcFacade } from 'ng-oidc-client';
import { User } from 'oidc-client';

// Constructor
constructor(private oidcFacade: OidcFacade) {}

// Method
isAuthenticated() {
    let isLoggedIn = this.oidcFacade.loggedIn$;
    if (!isLoggedIn) return false;
    return isLoggedIn;
}


// navbar.component.html
<li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]='["link-active"]' *ngIf="isAuthenticated() == true">
   <a class="nav-link" (click)='signOutRedirect()'>Sign Out</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the library creator followed the naming convention for observable, `this.oidcFacade.loggedIn$` is a type of boolean observable.

All you need to do is use the `async` pipe. `*ngIf="oidcFacade.loggedIn$ | async"`